# Stack corruption in message-encoding program

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a C++ program that creates a list of letters that will 
be used to encode a message according to the following rules:

1. Input a word
2. Remove all repeating letters to form the modified word
3. Place the modified word at the beginning of the array
4. Fill the remainder of the list with any letters of the alphabet that were not used in the word working from A to Z. (Your list should have all 26 letters of the alphabet)

For example, if the user enters `HELLO`, the modified word would become `HELO`, and the list would become `HELOABCDFGIJKMNPQRSTUVXYZ`. The list must be stored in an array of CHARacters.

This is the code I've written:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a;
    int b = 0;
    char word[4] = "\0";
    char alphabet[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char code[27];
    cout << "Please enter a word:" << endl;
    cin >> word;
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == word[i - 1])
        {
            a = word[i];
            word[i] = word[i + 1];
        }
        code[i] = word[i];
        b++;
    }
    for (int o = 0; o<27; o++)
    {
        if (alphabet[o] == word[1] || alphabet[o] == word[2] || alphabet[o] == word[3]  || alphabet[o] == word[0])
        {
            o++;
        }
        code[b] = alphabet[o];
        b++;
    }
    cout << code;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

> **Run-Time Check Failure #2**
>   Stack around the variable `word` was corrupted.

Secondly, my code works for 4 characters. How can I make it work for any word?

Comment: "i don't know whats wrong with my code" - you should describe some input for which it fails, what result it produces, what you expected, and where you get stuck in working out why....  This site is not for general code reviews - we need a specific problem.  (And  I hope you recognise this is a positive comment encouraging you to frame your question properly so people can and will help).

Comment: yes my fault. first- i'm getting this error -Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'word' was corrupted. second my code works for 4 character how can i make it work for any word?  Thanks

Comment: `if (word[i] == word[i - 1])` - what happens when `i == 0` like on the first iteration?

Comment: You should really look into `std::string` and `std::set`.  They make this problem trivial.

Comment: Should the repeated letters be removed even if they are not consecutive? If so you problem becomes easier by noting that the output string must always be 26 characters long.

Comment: Well, you can make the `word` array large enough for any imaginable word (a `std::string` would be better but maybe the spirit of the question is to avoid such conveniences), then use `size_t len = strlen(word);` to get its actual length in characters excluding the terminating NUL.  To check for letters, I recommend using `strchr`, as your current approach only finds repeating letters when they're side-by-side.  If you get as far as you can with those changes, post updated code and send me a comment if you want me to have another look....

Comment: (Oh, and the Stack Overflow "copy-assignment" tag is about the copy-assignment operator in C++: `X& operator=(const X&)`... not about homework/assignments.)

Comment: I would look at (int o = 0; o<27; o++) as alphabet only has 16 characters.  Since C++ indexing starts at 0, the the condition should be 0<26, not 27.  You may be trying to access alphabet[26] which would be outside of the array on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple way to do this assignment.
note that input word lenght should be smaller than 100

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[100]; // input word lenght should be smaller than 100
    char used[26];
    memset(used, 0, 26);
    scanf("%s", word);

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(word); i++)
    {
        // convert to uppercase
        if (word[i]>='a' && word[i]<='z')
            word[i] -= 'a'-'A';

        // skip non-alphabetic characters
        if (word[i]<'A' || word[i]>'Z')
            continue;

        // print this char only if it's not been printed before
        if (!used[word[i]-'A'])
            printf("%c", word[i]);

        // set to 1 so that we don't print it again
        used[word[i]-'A'] = 1;
    }

    // print all unused characters
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
        if (!used[i])
            printf("%c", i+'A');
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```